# Given definition of sine and cosine as in Spivak's Calculus, how do we prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to \pi/2} \tan{x}=\infty$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

In Spivak's *Calculus*, $\cos$ is defined by

$$A(\cos{x})=\frac{x}{2}\tag{1}$$

if $0\leq x\leq \pi$, where $$A(x)=\frac{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}+\int_x^1 \sqrt{1-t^2}dt\tag{2}$$ is the function giving the area of a sector of the unit circle starting at $(0,1)$ going counterclockwise.

If $\pi\leq x\leq 2\pi$ then $\cos{x}$ is defined

$$\cos{x}=\cos{(2\pi-x)}$$

and if $x=2\pi k+x'$ for $x'\in [0,2\pi]$ then $\cos{x}$ is defined

$$\cos{x}=\cos{x'}$$

$\sin$ is then defined as

$$\sin{x}=\sqrt{1-\cos^2{x}}$$

**Given these definitions, how do we prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to \pi/2} \tan{x}=\infty$?**

EDIT: I mean, how do we prove

$$\lim\limits_{x\to (\pi/2)^-} \tan{x}=\infty$$

Comment: The claim isn't true, but we do have the one-sided limit $\lim_{x \nearrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \tan x = +\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Firts of all note that you want to prove that $\lim_{x\to \pi/2^+}\tan x=+\infty$, because $\lim_{x\to \pi/2^-}\tan x=-\infty$, so be careful. Now, by the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, for any constant $K\in \mathbb{R}$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $x\in(\pi/2-\delta,\pi/2)$ then $\tan(x)>K$.

Take $\delta=\frac\pi2-\arctan K$. Then,$$x\in\left(\frac\pi2-\delta,\frac\pi2\right)\iff\arctan K<x<\frac\pi2\implies\tan x>K.$$

An alternative
$$\lim_{x\to \pi/2^-}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\lim_{x\to \pi/2^-}\frac{\sqrt{1-cos^2 x}}{\cos x}=\lim_{x\to \pi/2^-}\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{\cos^2 x}}=\lim_{t\to 0^-}\sqrt{\frac{1-t^2}{t^2}}=+\infty$$

Comment: well put! +1.  I like the alternative approach more, its cleaner.

Comment: I think perhaps the wording should be different though. For any $K>0$ let $\delta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan{K}>0$. Then $\arctan{K}<x<\pi/2 \implies \tan{x}>K$. Ie, for any $K>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $\pi/2-\delta<x<\pi/2 \implies \tan{x}>K$. Therefore, $\lim\limits_{x\to (\pi/2)^-} \tan{x}=\infty$.

Comment: there is some issue with potential circularity here. The first is regarding the wording of the proof mentioned by @evianpring. Next, how much are we really allowed to assume about $\arctan$ though? Knowing that $\arctan$ (which Spivak defines as the inverse of $\tan|_{(-\pi/2,\pi/2)}$) has domain $\Bbb{R}$ is equivalent to showing that $\tan$ has range $\Bbb{R}$, so I feel like the first approach doesn't really prove much; it covers up one issue with another. The alternative proof however is good (though you don't need to write $\sin x=\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$) because it uses already known facts.

Comment: For any $K>0$, we know that $\arctan{K}<\pi/2$ because of the following facts: $\tan$ is increasing and one-one on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ (hence $\arctan$ exists and is one-one increasing on this interval), and $\arctan$ is defined in terms of this particular interval and so this is its image. So then we take an $x$ between $\arctan{K}$ and $\pi/2$ and get $\arctan{K}<x<\pi/2$. Since $\tan$ is increasing, we know that $\tan{(\arctan{K})}<\tan{x}$ and hence that $\tan{x}>K$. Where is the circularity? @peek-a-boo

Comment: @evianpring yes $\tan$ is increasing and hence injective on the interval. So it's image is an open interval $J$. But how do you know that $J=\Bbb{R}$? In other words, you know that for some $J$, the function $\arctan:J\to (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ is defined, but how do you know the domain is the whole of $\Bbb{R}$? So how do you know something like $\arctan(100)$ is even well-defined? Proving this amounts to proving the limit in your question. By the logic in your comment, every increasing function has a limit of $\infty$ which is obviously wrong.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see your point. So the proof using $\arctan$ is incorrect. Indeed if we prove that $\tan$ takes on all values in $\mathbb{R}^+$ for $x>0$ then we will probably have proved the result about the limit as $x\to \pi/2$. The derivative of $\tan$ is $\frac{1}{\cos^2{x}}>0$, and the second derivative is $\frac{2\sin{x}}{\cos^3{x}}>0$ for $x \in (0,\pi/2)$. Also, $\lim\limits_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}} [\tan{x}]'=\infty$. I believe this path offers a way to prove the desired result as well.

Comment: First and second derivatives being positive by itself is still not good enough...