# Given definition of sine and cosine as in Spivak's Calculus, how do we prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \arctan{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, solution-verification

In Spivak's *Calculus*, $\cos$ is defined by

$$A(\cos{x})=\frac{x}{2}\tag{1}$$

if $0\leq x\leq \pi$, where $$A(x)=\frac{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}+\int_x^1 \sqrt{1-t^2}dt\tag{2}$$ is the function giving the area of a sector of the unit circle starting at $(0,1)$ going counterclockwise.

If $\pi\leq x\leq 2\pi$ then $\cos{x}$ is defined

$$\cos{x}=\cos{(2\pi-x)}$$

and if $x=2\pi k+x'$ for $x'\in [0,2\pi]$ then $\cos{x}$ is defined

$$\cos{x}=\cos{x'}$$

$\sin$ is then defined as

$$\sin{x}=\sqrt{1-\cos^2{x}}$$

**Given these definitions, how do we prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \arctan{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$?**

Here is what I came up with

Let $\epsilon>0$.

Then

$$\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Let $x$ be any number such that $x>\tan{\left (\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon\right)}$. Then

$$\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon<\arctan{x}<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Therefore, we have shown that

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists M>0\ \forall x,x>M\implies|\arctan{x}-\frac{\pi}{2}|<\epsilon$$

$$\implies \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \arctan{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

**Is this proof correct?**

Comment: If you already proved $\tan$ is increasing and maps $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ **onto** $\Bbb{R}$, then yes this is fine. But this requires you to know that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are positive on $(0,\pi/2)$ and have limits of $1$ and $0$ respectively; then you can show that $\tan$ which is the quotient, has a limit of $\infty$ (i.e the alternative proof in the answer to your previous question).

Comment: The previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4496296/given-definition-of-sine-and-cosine-as-in-spivaks-calculus-how-do-we-prove-tha

Comment: Considering that Spivak uses $\pi$ in his def'n of $\cos$, how does he define $\pi$?

Comment: He defines $\pi$ as $\pi=2\cdot \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$